# Gitlab installation error on bundle exec command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab

I am following [this](http://qiita.com/gumob@github/items/3960f8e8bb7159a4ac16) tutorial in order tot setup gitlab on my Centos vps.

While executing this command:

`bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production --trace`

I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
libicui18n.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
- /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/
2.1.0-static/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
```

`charlock_holmes` is installed. What else could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

See if the [comment in issue 7 of `charlock_holmes`](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes/issues/7#issuecomment-44606075) works for your case.
It was mentioned in [gitlabhd issue 8381](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8381).

> My (overkill) solution was to reinstall the bundle:

```
mv /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby.orig
```

(the issue was for reinstalling `charlock_holmes`:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

)

In your case, you would repeat the gitlab install process.

Comment: @FilipLuch Then that would need to be reported as an issue, like https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8381 was.